# Change money with python dynamic programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

Here are two programs for change money problem. The first one is only a recursion program that get all combinations and the second one is using dynamic programming. HOWEVER, i get into trouble when I am working on second one. It is supposed to be faster than the first one, but my program runs FOREVER to do it. I am pretty sure that I am using the dynamic programming, but i don't know what's the problem in it?

Notes: Total is the money going to be changed, units is a list with different values and stored is a dictionary to store the value of a step.

First:

```
def changeMoney(total, units):
    if ( total == 0 ): 
        return [{}]
    elif ( total < 0 ):
        return []
    else:
        n = len(units)
        ret = []
        for i in range(0,n):
            sols = changeMoney(total-units[i],units[i:n])
            for sol in sols:
                if ( units[i] in sol ):
                    sol[units[i]] += 1
                else:
                    sol[units[i]] = 1
            ret.append(sol)
        return ret
print(dpChangeMoney(300,[100,50,20,10,5,2,1],{}))
```

Second:

```
import copy
def dpChangeMoney(total, units, stored):
    key = ".".join(map(str,[total] + units))
    if key in stored:
        return stored[key]
    else:
        if ( total == 0 ):
            return [{}]
        elif ( total < 0 ):
            return []
        else:
            n = len(units)
            for i in range(0,n):
                sols = copy.deepcopy(dpChangeMoney(total-
units[i],units[i:n], stored))
                for sol in sols:
                    if ( units[i] in sol ):
                        sol[units[i]] += 1
                    else:
                        sol[units[i]] = 1
                    if key in stored:
                        if sol not in stored[key]:
                            stored[key] += [sol]
                    else:
                        stored[key] = [sol]
        return stored[key]
print(dpChangeMoney(300,[100,50,20,10,5,2,1],{}))
```

Comment: The numbers in units are assumed to be integers and in a decreasing order.

Comment: You should just use a tuple for the dict key, rather than constructing a string.

Comment: @TomKarzes but that is not time consuming i guess?

Comment: Correct, it's a bit less efficient and needlessly complicates the code, but it's not causing your problem.

Comment: the core point in dp is state transition equation.In money change it's `d[s]=min{d[s-v[i]]+1, d[s]} `.Do you need a example?

Comment: @obgnaw Thank you but this is not calculating the minimum coins or calculating how many ways in total. The function here is going to show all combinations which is more complex i think. But anyway thanks. Also there is a requirement to use dictionary here.

Comment: in your case,you should try DFS,DP is not suitable for  combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much faster way to do this:

```
def dpChangeMoney(total, units, stored, min_ix=0):
    if total < 0:
        return []

    if total == 0:
        return [{}]

    if min_ix == len(units):
        return []

    key = (total, min_ix)
    if key in stored:
        return stored[key]

    sol_list = []
    u = units[min_ix]
    for c in range(total // u + 1):
        sols = dpChangeMoney(total - c*u, units, stored, min_ix + 1)
        for sol in sols:
            if c > 0:
                sol2 = sol.copy()
                sol2[u] = c
            else:
                sol2 = sol
            sol_list.append(sol2)

    stored[key] = sol_list
    return sol_list
```

If invoked as follows, it prints the number of solutions for the specified case:

```
print(len(dpChangeMoney(300, [100,50,20,10,5,2,1], {})))
```

The result is:

```
466800
```

On my system this took well under a second to run.  (Of course, you could print the actual solutions, but there are a lot!)

To see the actual solutions for a total of `10`:

```
print(dpChangeMoney(10, [100,50,20,10,5,2,1], {}))
```

The result is:

```
[{1: 10}, {1: 8, 2: 1}, {1: 6, 2: 2}, {1: 4, 2: 3}, {1: 2, 2: 4}, {2: 5}, {1: 5, 5: 1}, {1: 3, 2: 1, 5: 1}, {1: 1, 2: 2, 5: 1}, {5: 2}, {10: 1}]
```

Comment: THAT IS COOL!!!!!!! I would try it some time later but definitely, this algorithm will be a master-level program if it runs in a second!!!!

Comment: If you study it, I think you'll be able to figure it out.  I simplified the hash key and eliminated the need to keep copying slices of `units`, but I think one of the biggest speed improvements was eliminating the list search when adding a new solution (which is *really* slow).  Instead, I generate the solutions in such a way that there cannot be any duplicates, so I can skip the check.

Answer (score 0):

i just figure out what is the problem in my algorithm. I will update a much faster algorithm after the due date. Thanks for your suggestions and instructions. E